# SQL SERVER 2008 Error while creating a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a script while creating a table. And I get this error message:

> CONDITIONAL failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use
>   with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations.

The create table script is below. Any ideas and suggestions!

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Account]    Script Date: 04/24/2012 10:06:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account](
    [accountID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [crmAccountID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [crmOwningUserID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [crmBusinessUnitID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](160) NULL,
    [accountNumber] [nvarchar](160) NULL,
    [stateCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [topClientOfFirm] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [topClientOfCMG] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [balanceOfTrade] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [websiteURL] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [clientLevel] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [industryCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [city] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [state] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [country] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [numProperties] [int] NULL,
    [numEquityNeeds] [int] NULL,
    [numDebtNeeds] [int] NULL,
    [numCompanyLocations] [int] NULL,
    [numDebtPositions] [int] NULL,
    [primaryContactID] [int] NULL,
    [parentAccountID] [int] NULL,
    [tickerSymbol] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [negativeExperiences] [smallint] NULL,
    [totalSubAccounts] [smallint] NULL,
    [topParentAccountID] [int] NULL,
    [knownAs] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [lenderType] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [investorLender] [tinyint] NULL,
    [primaryGeography] [bit] NULL,
    [secondaryGeography] [bit] NULL,
    [teriaryGeography] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [accountID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: is the DB where you are creating this table part of a replication schema?

Comment: Please follow the links given below... May help you in solving the issue [ http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/cb5fc0cd-b3dd-40bd-b23a-4270a0206844/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/cb5fc0cd-b3dd-40bd-b23a-4270a0206844/) [http://www.sqlteam.com/Forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=165844](http://www.sqlteam.com/Forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=165844)